# Alternative of QueueingConsumer in later version of RabbitMQ client

Tags: rabbitmq

What is alternative for QueueingConsumer in the latest version(5.1.2) of RabbitMQ? What should the consumer look like in case of basic QOS is greater than 1 i.e channel.basicQos(5);

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in RabbitMQ Doc

> it is now safe to implement `Consumer` directly or
>   to extend `DefaultConsumer` and `QueueingConsumer`
>   is a lot less relevant.

If you use channel.basicQos(5); In this case server prefetch this count for consumer.